# Watson NLC training data and commas in user questions

Tags: ibm-watson

In analyzing questions submitted by users, I see that sometimes users include commas. When that happens, it affects the structure of the CSV file so that the classification is no longer... question, class, question, class... but rather... question segment 1, question segment 2, class, question segment 1, question segment 2, question segment 3, class,... etc.

This inadvertent change to the .csv training data file format seems like it will cause problems when training a classifier. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

NLC should support quote wrapped CSV.

Example:

```
"Hi, where can I reset my password", PASSWORD_RESET
```

If that isn't the case, then expand your question.

Comment: Trouble is I can't control what the user types in... are you suggesting preprocessing - wrapping every question?

Comment: You wrap the users input with quotes before sending to NLC.